# Odoo <t t-call="website.layout"> qWebException

Tags: templates, web, odoo, openerp-8

When I add   to my templates I get the following error

```
QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'" while evaluating
'res_company.name'
```

the template code:

```
<template id="index" >
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <t t-set="title">Academy</t>
            <div class="oe_structure">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul><t t-foreach="brands" t-as="b">
                        <li><a t-attf-href="/pa/{{b.id}}">
                            <t t-esc="b.name"/>
                        </a></li>
                    </t></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the model structure that you are using in this shown template? this will provide better idea to identify the issue.

Comment: yes http://pastebin.com/GrEUcM4V

Answer (score 12):

The problem was in the controler, I've to append the website=True

```
@http.route('/pa/', auth='public', website=True)
```

Comment: Do you know why this is required?

Comment: old but gold, you sir are a paragon